# Ansible win_reg_stat - how to query windows registry sub keys using loop and with_items

Tags: ansible, registry

Good Day
I'm trying to check whether sub keys under a registry key path exist using with_items and loop methods.

**OBJECTIVE**
Query *exists* value for a group of registry sub keys as shown in the sample code below.

**QUESTION**
Why method 3 did not work to give results similar to the sample code below?

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
  - name: TEST query
    win_reg_stat:
      path: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\PublicProfile
      name: DisableNotifications
    register: reg_val
  - name: DEBUG TEST QUERY display registry values
    debug:
      msg="{{ reg_val }}"
    ignore_errors: yes
```

> TASK [TEST query]
> **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************** Wednesday 04 August 2021  16:18:21 +0800 (0:00:00.108)
> 0:00:00.108 ****** ok: [ipcprdixn201]
>
> TASK [DEBUG TEST QUERY display registry values]
> ********************************************************************************************************************************************************** Wednesday 04 August 2021  16:18:24 +0800 (0:00:03.234)
> 0:00:03.343 ****** ok: [ipcprdixn201] => {
> "msg": {
> "changed": false,
> "exists": true,
> "failed": false,
> "raw_value": 0,
> "type": "REG_DWORD",
> "value": 0
> } }

Below are three methods that I tried.

**METHOD 1**
*code:*

```
  - name: SUB QUERY registry values WindowsFirewall\PublicProfile Logging
    win_reg_stat:
      path: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\PublicProfile\{{ item }}
    loop:
      -  { 'DisableNotifications' }
      -  { 'DefaultInboundAction' }
    register: reg_val
  - name: DEBUG SUB QUERY display registry values
    debug:
      msg="{{ reg_val}}"
    ignore_errors: yes
```

**METHOD 1**
*result:*

> TASK [SUB QUERY registry values WindowsFirewall\PublicProfile Logging]
> *********************************************************************************************************************************** Wednesday 04 August 2021  15:56:22 +0800 (0:00:00.122)
> 0:00:00.122 ****** ok: [ipcprdixn201] =>
> (item={u'DisableNotifications': None}) ok: [ipcprdixn201] =>
> (item={u'DefaultInboundAction': None})
>
> TASK [DEBUG SUB QUERY display registry values]
> *********************************************************************************************************************************************************** Wednesday 04 August 2021  15:56:30 +0800 (0:00:08.062)
> 0:00:08.184 ****** ok: [ipcprdixn201] => {
> "msg": [
> {
> "ansible_loop_var": "item",
> "changed": false,
> "exists": false,
> "failed": false,
> "item": {
> "DisableNotifications": null
> }
> },
> {
> "ansible_loop_var": "item",
> "changed": false,
> "exists": false,
> "failed": false,
> "item": {
> "DefaultInboundAction": null
> }
> }

**METHOD 2**
*code:*

```
  - name: TOP QUERY registry values WindowsFirewall\PublicProfile
    win_reg_stat:
      path: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\PublicProfile
    register: reg_val
  - name: DEBUG TOP QUERY display registry values
    debug:
      msg="{{ reg_val }}"
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: SUB QUERY registry values WindowsFirewall\PublicProfile Logging
    win_reg_stat:
      path: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\PublicProfile\{{ item }}
    loop: "{{ reg_val.sub_keys }}"
    register: reg_val
  - name: DEBUG SUB QUERY display registry values
    debug:
      msg="{{ reg_val}}"
    ignore_errors: yes
```

**METHOD 2**
*result:*

> TASK [TOP QUERY registry values WindowsFirewall\PublicProfile]
> ******************************************************************************************************************************************* Wednesday 04 August 2021  15:58:40 +0800 (0:00:00.124)
> 0:00:00.124 ****** ok: [ipcprdixn201]
>
> TASK [DEBUG TOP QUERY display registry values]
> *********************************************************************************************************************************************************** Wednesday 04 August 2021  15:58:43 +0800 (0:00:03.007)
> 0:00:03.131 ****** ok: [ipcprdixn201] => {
> "msg": {
> "changed": false,
> "exists": true,
> "failed": false,
> "properties": {
> "AllowLocalIPsecPolicyMerge": {
> "raw_value": 1,
> "type": "REG_DWORD",
> "value": 1
> },
> "AllowLocalPolicyMerge": {
> "raw_value": 1,
> "type": "REG_DWORD",
> "value": 1
> },
> "DefaultInboundAction": {
> "raw_value": 1,
> "type": "REG_DWORD",
> "value": 1
> },
> "DefaultOutboundAction": {
> "raw_value": 0,
> "type": "REG_DWORD",
> "value": 0
> },
> "DisableNotifications": {
> "raw_value": 0,
> "type": "REG_DWORD",
> "value": 0
> },
> "DisableUnicastResponsesToMulticastBroadcast": {
> "raw_value": 1,
> "type": "REG_DWORD",
> "value": 1
> },
> "EnableFirewall": {
> "raw_value": 1,
> "type": "REG_DWORD",
> "value": 1
> }
> },
> "sub_keys": [
> "Logging"
> ]
> } }
>
> Wednesday 04 August 2021  15:58:43 +0800 (0:00:00.054)
> 0:00:03.186 ******
> [0/2907] ok: [ipcprdixn201] => (item=Logging)
>
> TASK [DEBUG SUB QUERY display registry values]
> *********************************************************************************************************************************************************** Wednesday 04 August 2021  15:58:46 +0800 (0:00:02.934)
> 0:00:06.121 ****** ok: [ipcprdixn201] => {
> "msg": {
> "changed": false,
> "msg": "All items completed",
> "results": [
> {
> "ansible_loop_var": "item",
> "changed": false,
> "exists": true,
> "failed": false,
> "item": "Logging",
> "properties": {
> "LogDroppedPackets": {
> "raw_value": 1,
> "type": "REG_DWORD",
> "value": 1
> },
> "LogFilePath": {
> "raw_value": "%windir%\system32\logfiles\firewall\publicfirewall.log",
> "type": "REG_SZ",
> "value": "%windir%\system32\logfiles\firewall\publicfirewall.log"
> },
> "LogFileSize": {
> "raw_value": 16384,
> "type": "REG_DWORD",
> "value": 16384
> },
> "LogSuccessfulConnections": {
> "raw_value": 1,
> "type": "REG_DWORD",
> "value": 1
> }
> },
> "sub_keys": []
> }
> ]
> } }

**METHOD 3**
*code:*

```
  - name: SUB QUERY registry values WindowsFirewall\PublicProfile
    win_reg_stat:
      path: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\PublicProfile}
      name: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - { 'DisableNotifications' }
      - { 'DefaultInboundAction' }
      - { 'DefaultOutboundAction' }
      - { 'EnableFirewall' }
      - { 'Logging' }
    register: reg_val
  - name: DEBUG SUB QUERY display registry values
    debug:
      msg="{{ reg_val}}"
```

**METHOD 3**
*result:*

> TASK [SUB QUERY registry values WindowsFirewall\PublicProfile]
> ******************************************************************************************************************************************* Wednesday 04 August 2021  16:02:24 +0800 (0:00:00.146)
> 0:00:00.146 ****** ok: [ipcprdixn201] =>
> (item={u'DisableNotifications': None}) ok: [ipcprdixn201] =>
> (item={u'DefaultInboundAction': None}) ok: [ipcprdixn201] =>
> (item={u'DefaultOutboundAction': None}) ok: [ipcprdixn201] =>
> (item={u'EnableFirewall': None}) ok: [ipcprdixn201] =>
> (item={u'Logging': None})
>
> TASK [DEBUG SUB QUERY display registry values]
> *********************************************************************************************************************************************************** Wednesday 04 August 2021  16:02:37 +0800 (0:00:13.735)
> 0:00:13.882 ****** ok: [ipcprdixn201] => {
> "msg": {
> "changed": false,
> "msg": "All items completed",
> "results": [
> {
> "ansible_loop_var": "item",
> "changed": false,
> "exists": false,
> "failed": false,
> "item": {
> "DisableNotifications": null
> }
> },
> {
> "ansible_loop_var": "item",
> "changed": false,
> "exists": false,
> "failed": false,
> "item": {
> "DefaultInboundAction": null
> }
> },
> {
> "ansible_loop_var": "item",
> "changed": false,
> "exists": false,
> "failed": false,
> "item": {
> "DefaultOutboundAction": null
> }
> },
> {
> "ansible_loop_var": "item",
> "changed": false,
> "exists": false,
> "failed": false,
> "item": {
> "EnableFirewall": null
> }
> },
> {
> "ansible_loop_var": "item",
> "changed": false,
> "exists": false,
> "failed": false,
> "item": {
> "Logging": null
> }
> }
> ]
> } }

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: my knowledge about Windows in general and Windows registry in particular is extremely limited, and I have no machine to test this against.*

---

If your sample code is doing what you expect, why are you trying to do it differently when you loop?

- You are passing different options to the module (e.g. `name` option disappears on some examples....)
- You are using a different kind of data from your loops (your sample is using a string as name whereas you loop over a list of single keyed null value objects...)

I have a hard time to understand your exact problem as your question is a sea of code and output without real errors, no explanation of what is doing the job or not and what you are expecting exactly instead.

At this point, from your original sample and what I think I understood from your examples I would just try:

```yaml
- name: TEST query with a loop
    win_reg_stat:
      path: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\PublicProfile
      name: "{{ item }}"
    register: reg_val
    loop:
      - DisableNotifications
      - DefaultInboundAction
      - DefaultOutboundAction
      - EnableFirewall
      - Logging

  - name: DEBUG TEST QUERY with all results
    debug:
      msg: "{{ reg_val }}"

  # Just a clue for future tasks you might want to write...
  - name: Alternatively debug each result independently
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ reg_val.results }}"
```